# Need explanation on this regex

Tags: regex

I have this regex used to split a string:

```
,(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)
```

e.g. string

"Field1","Field2","item1,item2,item3","Hello,""John"""

The one thing I understand is it is splitting the string on , but anything after that I am not sure.

If anyone can explain this Regex please.

If you can dissect it to the simplest possible level, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex is matching a comma `,` **only if it is outside double quotes** by counting even number of quotes after literal `,`.

---

**Explanation:**

```
, -> match literal comma
(?=...) -> positive lookahead
[^"]*" -> match anything before a " followed by a literal "
[^"]*"[^"]*" -> match a pair of above 
(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")* -> Match 0 or more of pairs (0, 2, 4, 6 sets)
[^"]*$ -> Followed by any non-quote till end of string
```

**Example Input:**

```
"Field1,Field2","Field3","item1,item2,item3"
```

- First it will match `,` before `"Field3"` because lookahead: `(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)` is making sure there are 4 double quotes after this comma.
- Second it will match `,` after `"Field3"` because lookahead: `(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)` is making sure there are 2 double quotes after this comma.
- It is not matching comma between `Field1` and `Field2` because # of quotes after that are odd in numbers and hence lookahead `(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)` will fail.

Comment: I understand that part but need to understand it part by part so I can create something similar myself.

Comment: Ok I added some more explanation, let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: Thanks got little more understanding but would it be possible to explain a bit more using the example string I have above.

Comment: ok [see this demo link](http://regex101.com/r/gE5yO7/1) with above regex and a simplified example. I will add more explanation

Comment: Now your initial explanation steps makes more sense to me. The demo link was helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
,(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)
```

This will not split on `,` which are inside `"` and `"`.This says that after every `,` there will be groups of `something " something"`.So effectively `,` cannot be in between `"` and `"`.

Comment: Thanks...I understand that part but need to understand it part by part so I can create something similar myself.

Comment: @gbs if a `,` is in between `"` and `"` it will have odd number of `"` ahead of it.If it is outside it will have even number of `"` ahead of it.hope that helps